# Circle line segment collision

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I need to detect collision circle with any line. I have array with verticles of polygon (x, y) and draw this polygon in loop. For detection I use algorithm, which calculate triangle height. Then I check if this height < 0, then circle collided with line.

The picture, that describe this method:

[image]

But I have unexpected result. My circle collide with transparent line (what?). I can't explain how it happens.

Demo at jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f458rdz6/1/

Function, which check the collisions and response it:

```
var p = polygonPoints;

for (var i = 0, n = p.length; i < n; i++) {
    var start = i;
    var end = (i + 1) % n;

    var x0 = p[start].x;
    var y0 = p[start].y;
    var x1 = p[end].x;
    var y1 = p[end].y;

    // detection collision
    var dx = x1 - x0;
    var dy = y1 - y0;

    var len = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    var dist = (dx * (this.y - y0) - dy * (this.x - x0)) / len;

    if (dist < this.radius) {
        continue;
    }

    // calculate reflection, because collided
    var wallAngle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
    var wallNormalX = Math.sin(wallAngle);
    var wallNormalY = -Math.cos(wallAngle);

    var d = 2 * (this.velocityX * wallNormalX + this.velocityY * wallNormalY);
    this.x -= d * wallNormalX;
    this.y -= d * wallNormalY;
}
```

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var polygonPoints = [
 {
     x: 240,
        y: 130
    },
    {
     x: 140,
        y: 100
    },
    {
     x: 180,
        y: 250
    },
    {
     x: 320,
        y: 280
    },
    {
     x: 400,
        y: 50
    }
];

var game = {
 ball: new Ball()
};

function Ball() {
 this.x = canvas.width / 2;
    this.y = canvas.height - 100;
    this.oldX = this.x - 1;
    this.oldY = this.y + 1;
    this.velocityX = 0;
    this.velocityY = 0;
    this.radius = 8;
};

Ball.prototype.draw = function() {
 ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#0095DD';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
};

Ball.prototype.update = function() {
 var x = this.x;
    var y = this.y;
    
    this.velocityX = this.x - this.oldX;
    this.velocityY = this.y - this.oldY;
    
    this.x += this.velocityX;
    this.y += this.velocityY;
    
    this.oldX = x;
    this.oldY = y;
};

Ball.prototype.collision = function() {
 var p = polygonPoints;
    
 for (var i = 0, n = p.length; i < n; i++) {
     var start = i;
        var end = (i + 1) % n;
        
        var x0 = p[start].x;
        var y0 = p[start].y;
        var x1 = p[end].x;
        var y1 = p[end].y;
        
        // detection collision
        var dx = x1 - x0;
        var dy = y1 - y0;
        
        var len = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        var dist = (dx * (this.y - y0) - dy * (this.x - x0)) / len;
        
        if (dist < this.radius) {
         continue;
        }

  // calculate reflection, because collided
        var wallAngle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
        var wallNormalX = Math.sin(wallAngle);
        var wallNormalY = -Math.cos(wallAngle);

        var d = 2 * (this.velocityX * wallNormalX + this.velocityY * wallNormalY);
        this.x -= d * wallNormalX;
        this.y -= d * wallNormalY;
    }
};


function drawBall() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}

function drawPolygon() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#333';
    ctx.moveTo(polygonPoints[0].x, polygonPoints[0].y);
 for (var i = 1, n = polygonPoints.length; i < n; i++) {
     ctx.lineTo(polygonPoints[i].x, polygonPoints[i].y);
    }
    ctx.lineTo(polygonPoints[0].x, polygonPoints[0].y);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}

function render() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    drawPolygon();
    game.ball.draw();
    game.ball.update();
    game.ball.collision();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

render();
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>
```

What the problem? Maybe I need use other method for detect collision? I tried to use [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36523711/2811430), but if my circle has high speed this method not working.

Thank you.

Answer (score 22):

## Circle line segment intercept

**UPDATE**

This answer includes line line intercept, moving a line along its normal, distance point (circle) to line, and circle line intercept.

The circle is

```
var circle = {
    radius : 500,
    center : point(1000,1000),
}
```

The line segment is

```
var line = {
    p1 : point(500,500),
    p2 : point(2000,1000),
}
```

A point is

```
var point = {
    x : 100,
    y : 100,
}
```

Thus the function to find the intercept of a line segment width a circle

The function returns an array of up to two point on the line segment. If no points found returns an empty array.

```
function inteceptCircleLineSeg(circle, line){
    var a, b, c, d, u1, u2, ret, retP1, retP2, v1, v2;
    v1 = {};
    v2 = {};
    v1.x = line.p2.x - line.p1.x;
    v1.y = line.p2.y - line.p1.y;
    v2.x = line.p1.x - circle.center.x;
    v2.y = line.p1.y - circle.center.y;
    b = (v1.x * v2.x + v1.y * v2.y);
    c = 2 * (v1.x * v1.x + v1.y * v1.y);
    b *= -2;
    d = Math.sqrt(b * b - 2 * c * (v2.x * v2.x + v2.y * v2.y - circle.radius * circle.radius));
    if(isNaN(d)){ // no intercept
        return [];
    }
    u1 = (b - d) / c;  // these represent the unit distance of point one and two on the line
    u2 = (b + d) / c;    
    retP1 = {};   // return points
    retP2 = {}  
    ret = []; // return array
    if(u1 <= 1 && u1 >= 0){  // add point if on the line segment
        retP1.x = line.p1.x + v1.x * u1;
        retP1.y = line.p1.y + v1.y * u1;
        ret[0] = retP1;
    }
    if(u2 <= 1 && u2 >= 0){  // second add point if on the line segment
        retP2.x = line.p1.x + v1.x * u2;
        retP2.y = line.p1.y + v1.y * u2;
        ret[ret.length] = retP2;
    }       
    return ret;
}
```

**UPDATE**

**Line line intercept.**

Returns a point if found else returns undefined.

```
function interceptLines(line,line1){  
    var v1, v2, c, u;
    v1 = {};
    v2 = {};
    v3 = {};
    v1.x = line.p2.x - line.p1.x; // vector of line
    v1.y = line.p2.y - line.p1.y;
    v2.x = line1.p2.x - line1.p1.x; //vector of line2
    v2.y = line1.p2.y - line1.p1.y;
    var c = v1.x * v2.y - v1.y * v2.x; // cross of the two vectors
    if(c !== 0){ 
        v3.x = line.p1.x - line1.p1.x; 
        v3.y = line.p1.y - line1.p1.y;                
        u = (v2.x * v3.y - v2.y * v3.x) / c; // unit distance of intercept point on this line
        return {x : line.p1.x + v1.x * u, y : line.p1.y + v1.y * u};
    }
    return undefined;
}
```

**Lift Line**

Move line along its normal

```
function liftLine(line,dist){
    var v1,l
    v1 = {};
    v1.x = line.p2.x - line.p1.x; // convert line to vector
    v1.y = line.p2.y - line.p1.y;
    l = Math.sqrt(v1.x * v1.x + v1.y * v1.y); // get length;
    v1.x /= l;  // Assuming you never pass zero length lines
    v1.y /= l;
    v1.x *= dist; // set the length
    v1.y *= dist;
    // move the line along its normal the required distance
    line.p1.x -= v1.y;
    line.p1.y += v1.x;
    line.p2.x -= v1.y;
    line.p2.y += v1.x;

    return line; // if needed 
}
```

**Distance circle (or point) to a line segment**

Returns the closest distance to the line segment. It is just the circle center that I am using. So you can replace circle with a point

```
function circleDistFromLineSeg(circle,line){
    var v1, v2, v3, u;
    v1 = {};
    v2 = {};
    v3 = {};
    v1.x = line.p2.x - line.p1.x;
    v1.y = line.p2.y - line.p1.y;
    v2.x = circle.center.x - line.p1.x;
    v2.y = circle.center.y - line.p1.y;
    u = (v2.x * v1.x + v2.y * v1.y) / (v1.y * v1.y + v1.x * v1.x); // unit dist of point on line
    if(u >= 0 && u <= 1){
        v3.x = (v1.x * u + line.p1.x) - circle.center.x;
        v3.y = (v1.y * u + line.p1.y) - circle.center.y;
        v3.x *= v3.x;
        v3.y *= v3.y;
        return Math.sqrt(v3.y + v3.x); // return distance from line
    } 
    // get distance from end points
    v3.x = circle.center.x - line.p2.x;
    v3.y = circle.center.y - line.p2.y;
    v3.x *= v3.x;  // square vectors
    v3.y *= v3.y;    
    v2.x *= v2.x;
    v2.y *= v2.y;
    return Math.min(Math.sqrt(v2.y + v2.x), Math.sqrt(v3.y + v3.x)); // return smaller of two distances as the result
}
```

Comment: This method works if ball has low speed, but if speed is high, function not working. https://jsfiddle.net/cmx8arz2/ see console, If circle intersect line app should print array of intersection points, but speed of circle high and console log clear.

Comment: @rmpstmp Use a line line intercept, using the ball's trajectory as the second line. Move the line along its normal toward the ball by the balls radius. If the lines intersect then use that point to test how far the ball is from the original line segment. if at radius (add EPSILON) from any point on the line, or the endpoints you have hit the ball. Cross product will give what side a point is to a line +right -left and dot product div line leng squared will give the unit dist on the line along its normal to the point. Point and line need to be translated to put line start at zero

Comment: @rmpstmp Looking at the fiddle. Just move all the line segments inward by the ball's radius (along the line normals). The use the ball's trajectory as a line and do a line/line intercept. Find the closest intercept to the ball's current location and you have the point of intercept, no need for a circle line segment intercept

Comment: Okay, can you describe, what lines I should send to function `interceptLines(line,line1)`? One of lines should be wall line, but second? I think line from ball's center `(b.x, b.y)` for example, and what should be second point? Thank you.

Comment: @rmpstmp I have added functions you need. The second point of the  is the balls x,y plus the balls speed. You will get several intercepts. You need to get how far they are from the current ball pos. If they ar further than the balls speed nothing happened. Dang I forgot you have an irregular poly need to do a dist along line test. Will add the final function to answer

Comment: So, every frame, I get `x, y` which returns `interceptLines(line, line1)` (where **line** - coordinates of wall points, **line1** - coordinates of circle center and circle center plus velocity). And then I get distance from circle center to this `x, y` and check if distance > nothing happened, else I print distance. But I have same result, just open console and see that collision happened in unexcepted place. https://jsfiddle.net/f458rdz6/2/

Comment: @rmpstmp You need to move the wall lines in by the radius of the ball. You should add some simple functions to draw points and lines for debugging so you can visualize the results of the various tests. You need to do the distance from the line segment test I added to the answer. This will give the points of collision. Test dist from ball current these intercepts keeping only the smallest distance. Then if that distance is less than the ball speed you have hit a wall. Intercepts for inset wall, intercept dist from wall if less than rad dump point, then closest and under ball speed is a hit.,

Comment: You've coded some nice functionality here -- upvote! :-) Using your functions, one can create a line segment that represents the leading edge of the ball from its starting to its ending position. Then calculate the line-line intercept (leading-edge-line versus obstacle-line) to get the [initial collision point](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/temp01.png) of the ball versus obstacle. After that, calculate some rebound angles and life is good.