# Problems with the animation on the canvas

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

I want to make a smooth ride circles on a canvas but I can not deal with how to limit the speed, location.

I'm currently only able to move them.

My JS function `onload` with the function `animate`:

```
function loader() {
    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
    var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
    var radius = 100;
    var circles=[];
    circles.push({ x:centerX+15, y:centerY-15, style:'rgba(104, 217, 255, 70)'});
    circles.push({ x:centerX, y:centerY-15, style:'rgba(104, 217, 255, 70)'});
    circles.push({ x:centerX-15, y:centerY, style:'rgba(104, 217, 255, 70)'});
    circles.push({ x:centerX-10, y:centerY, style:'rgba(0, 144, 226, 70)'});
    circles.push({ x:centerX+10, y:centerY+10, style:'rgba(210, 255, 0, 70)'});
    circles.push({ x:centerX+10, y:centerY, style:'rgba(0, 144, 226, 70)'});
    circles.push({ x:centerX-5, y:centerY-5, style:'rgba(210, 255, 0, 70)'});
    circles.push({x:centerX, y:centerY, style:'white', move:0});
    // start the animation loop
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    function animate(time){
        for(var i = 0; i < circles.length-1; i++){
            circles[i].x+=Math.random(); 
        }
      // draw all in their new positions
      drawAll();
      // request another frame in the animation loop
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }

    function drawAll(){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        for(var i=0;i<circles.length;i++){     
            drawCircle(circles[i]);
      }
    }

    function drawCircle(circle){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(circle.x,circle.y,radius,0,2*Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = circle.style;
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    }

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(95,250);
    ctx.lineTo(120,275);
    ctx.lineTo(150,225);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 144, 226, 70)';
    ctx.fill();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give each circle a horizontal and vertical speed:

```
circles.push({
    x:centerX+15, y:centerY-15, 
    style:'rgba(104, 217, 255, 70)',
    speedX:Math.random()*3,
    speedY:Math.random()*3,
});
```

Then during the animation you can smoothly change circle.x by speedX and change circle.y by speedY.

```
circles[i].x += circles[i].speedX;
circles[i].y += circles[i].speedY;
```

**Example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
var radius = 50;
var circles=[];
circles.push({ x:centerX+15, y:centerY-15, style:'rgba(104, 217, 255, 70)'});
circles.push({ x:centerX, y:centerY-15, style:'rgba(104, 217, 255, 70)'});
circles.push({ x:centerX-15, y:centerY, style:'rgba(104, 217, 255, 70)'});
circles.push({ x:centerX-10, y:centerY, style:'rgba(0, 144, 226, 70)'});
circles.push({ x:centerX+10, y:centerY+10, style:'rgba(210, 255, 0, 70)'});
circles.push({ x:centerX+10, y:centerY, style:'rgba(0, 144, 226, 70)'});
circles.push({ x:centerX-5, y:centerY-5, style:'rgba(210, 255, 0, 70)'});
circles.push({x:centerX, y:centerY, style:'white', move:0});

// add speeds
for(var i=0;i<circles.length;i++){
    circles[i].speedX=1+Math.random()*2;
    circles[i].speedY=1+Math.random()*2;
}

// start the animation loop
requestAnimationFrame(animate);

function animate(time){
  for(var i = 0; i < circles.length-1; i++){
      circles[i].x += circles[i].speedX;
      circles[i].y += circles[i].speedY;
  }
  // draw all in their new positions
  drawAll();
  // request another frame in the animation loop
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

function drawAll(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    for(var i=0;i<circles.length;i++){     
        drawCircle(circles[i]);
  }
}

function drawCircle(circle){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(circle.x,circle.y,radius,0,2*Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = circle.style;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=512 height=512></canvas>
```

Comment: It doesn't work, the animation starts, but it isn't visible.

Comment: Thank you)
You may know how can restrict their movement? that they don't extend beyond the canvas

Comment: You're welcome! If you want to learn more about collision testing then see this previous [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36523507/detection-and-response-ball-to-wall-collision-inside-any-polygon/36523711#36523711). Good luck with your project!